# C++ overloaded visitor view

Tags: c++, functional-programming, overloading

Looking at the following code used for overloading multiple callables, combining them into a single callable:

```
template<typename... F>
struct overloaded;

template<typename F, typename... Frest>
struct overloaded<F, Frest...> : F, overloaded<Frest...>
{
    overloaded(F&& f0, Frest&&... rest) 
        : F(std::forward<F>(f0))
        , overloaded<Frest...>(std::forward<Frest>(rest)...) 
    {}

    using F::operator();
    using overloaded<Frest...>::operator();
};

template<typename F>
struct overloaded<F> : F
{
    overloaded(F&& f0) 
        : F(std::forward<F>(f0)) 
    {}

    using F::operator();
};

template<typename... F>
auto overload(F&&... fs)
{
    return overloaded<F...>(std::forward<F>(fs)...);
}
```

Would it be possible to create similar overloaded callable without owning the callable objects (kind of like a function_view)? Since we cannot inherit from references how would this be done.

Comment: Create a simple `function_view` (without overloaded) ? Then you have to choose about fixed signature (disallowing generic lambda), or SFINAE `operator()` but then you will lose free overload resolution with class `overloaded`.